# Flutter FormatException

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have a controller for a TextFormField show decimal numbers from the text input. here is my code:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      final text = _controller.text;
      final amount = int.parse(text);
      final showAmount = (amount/100).toStringAsFixed(2);
      _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
          text: showAmount,
          selection: TextSelection(
            baseOffset: showAmount.length,
            extentOffset: showAmount.length,
          ),
          composing: TextRange.empty
      );
    });
  }
```

It works, however in the console I keep getting the following exception: 
*The following FormatException was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController:
Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)*

Is there a better way to parse into an int or show a string with decimal numbers?

Comment: I guess the text is null initially, this should fix it `int.parse(text??'0')`.

Comment: Is the `TextField` intended for `int` input only? 
If Yes, restrict the input to digits. 
Also as @ShubhamGupta mentioned, initially the input `isEmpty` and `int.parse` fails on encountering anything other than **0 to 9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to provide the below changes in this small code sample [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DvWqH6mX),

1. Added a separate `readOnly` `TextField` for the output.
2. Restricted the input `TextField` to intgers only using `keyboardType: TextInputType.number,` and `inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]`.
3. Added checks for `isEmpty` and initial value is set to blank String.

Hope this helps.